# Pre-build action

Tags: c#, rider

As part of a build process, I need to replace some of the code in a c# project at pre-build time. I hoped there is some hook available to specify in `.csproj` file. I am using Rider. This article appears to be about what I need; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2019, but I am not sure how to use it in `.csproj`.

How do you specify pre-build actions in c#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio add pre-build event that always runs (C# project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916414/visual-studio-add-pre-build-event-that-always-runs-c-project)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a BeforeBuild target in your csproj to run a command. Say, for example, I had a PS script I wanted to run:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">                                                                    
   <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted 
             -command &quot;&amp; invoke-command -scriptblock { 
                      &amp;&apos;$(ScriptLocation)&apos; 
                      &apos;$(LogFileLocation)&apos;  
                      &apos;$(MSDeployComputerName)&apos;}
                      &quot;"/>    
</Target>
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.csproj` you can add this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>start %25comspec%25</PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This only starts a cmd Window in that case but you can replace it. Also you can place it in the property group you want to use.
See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-events-page-project-designer-csharp?view=vs-2019)

Also I want to note the [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) specifically [#if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if). When you want to replace DEBUG Code, that only should be present in DEBUG Environment and it's a static replacement, this would be easier.